# Erdős succession question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

I am having trouble solving this contest question I found in a magazine:

> Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ be a succession of real positive numbers. We have for some $s\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ that
>   $$a_n=\max\{a_k+a_{n-k}:1\le k\le n-1\}$$
>   for every $n>s$.
>
> Prove that there exists $l,N\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ with $l\le s$ such that $a_n=a_l+a_{n-l}$ for every $n\ge N$.

Comment: Your last sentence is not easy to understand. What is $l$ doing there at all?

Comment: Sorry, sub index had to correspond to $l$ and I had left k there.

Comment: Should the constraints impose something on $a_n$ for $n>s$? Right now they only relate $n < s$ and you're trying to prove something about the tail...

Comment: @ChrisJones it was supposed to be $ n \gt s$ , my bad

Comment: Unless every one of the people voting to close it can produce a useful stab at a solution, this should not have been closed.